# UnicodeEncodeError: while using to_sql in python

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to insert dataframe to oracle database using to_sql. Below is the code:

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://'+username+':'+password+'@'+host+':'+port+'/'+sid)
df.to_sql(name = table.lower(),schema=schema,con =engine,if_exists = 'replace', index=False)

I am getting below error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 81: ordinal not in range(128)

can someone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your database is UTF8 and you did not export your NLS_LANG variable in your session:

So I would try to first export your NLS_LANG to the character set you have in your database:

```
#export NLS_LANG=American_America.AL32UTF8
```

Then I would try to change your connection in cx_Oracle.connect method:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/password@connectString",
    encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

As you are using to_sql , you might try this before you try your connection

```
import os
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = 'YOUR_NLS_LANG_VARIABLE'
```

Comment: only specifying NLS-LANG after importing libraries doesnt work.
how can I insert whole df using .connect method ?

Comment: do you know the character set of your database ? what error do you get when you use the df.to_sql method

Comment: It's worth noting that cx_Oracle 8 was just released.  (i) the default character set is now UTF-8 (ii) using NLS_LANG to set the character set no longer does anything.